# Javascript Regex replace []

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to replace the following in a Regex:-

```
[company-name]
```

Using Regex I would expect I could use was to use:-

```
str.replace(/[company-name]/g, 'Google');
```

But I know that the regex will replace any matching letter.

How am I able to replace the `[company-name]` with `Google` using JS Regex?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what is your example input string `str` value  and what output of that string you wanna get?

Comment: Literal square brackets need to be escaped. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special

Comment: You need to escape the brackets with \ since they have a meaning in regexps. Though in this case using regexps seems overkill if it’s just a string replace.

Comment: `[]` are meta characters. You need to escape them. `str.replace(/\[company-name\]/g, 'Google')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I know that the regex will replace any matching letter.

This is only the case because you have encapsulated your characters in a character class by using `[` and `]`. In order to treat these as normal characters, you can escape these using `\` in front of your special characters:

```
str.replace(/\[company-name\]/g, 'Google');
```

See working example below:

```js
const str = "[company-name]",
res = str.replace(/\[company-name\]/g, 'Google');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the starting `[` as well, in this case as they are [special characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) too:

```js
var str = "I am from [company-name]!";
console.log(str.replace(/\[company-name]/gi, "Google"));

str = "[company-name]'s awesome!";
console.log(str.replace(/\[company-name]/gi, "Google"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape special characters like square brackets in this case.
Just use:

```
str.replace(/\[company-name\]/g, 'Google');
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it this way :

```js
var txt = "So I'm working at [company-name] and thinking about getting a higher salary."
var pattern = /\[.+\]/g;
console.log(txt.replace(pattern, "Google"))
```